# Pandas - Get index of true/false

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4        True
        ...  
1569    False
1570    False
```

I need to get the indices that are True, so [4] in this case or something. How do i do that?

Comment: `df.col[lambda x: x].index`

Comment: IIUC `df[df[col].eq(True)].index.tolist()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: sorry its a series object

Comment: For Series, `s[s].index`

Comment: @Psidom I don't think the addition of adding `.index` warrants its own question - can you close as a duplicate?

Comment: `s[s].index` doesnt work. that just gives the index after the series has been modified. this will just give me 1, i want 4

Comment: I'm going to guess this is impossible, i just converted that pandas.series object into a numpy array and ran  a np.where operation to get the indicies

Comment: @raaj `s[s].index` should work. Check the linked duplicates plz.